# How to fetch newer foxy desktop packages?

Tags: ros, ros2, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All right, here we go: I have a new desktop computer with Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa installed. I want to run ROS2 on it, and it is supported by ROS2 Foxy. I had previously installed foxy desktop through the installation instructions, over two weeks ago. I followed the debian package instructions which can be found [here](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Install-Debians/)

When revisiting it today, I found out I needed to install colcon. It returned 'Failed to fetch' commands when installing.

I thought re-installing Foxy would be a possible solution, so I uninstalled it through

```
sudo apt remove ros-foxy-desktop
```

And tried to re-install it. However, this returns package fetch failures as well! See below:

```
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-rospkg-modules all 1.2.6-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-rospkg-modules/python3-rospkg-modules_1.2.6-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have tried both **sudo apt-get update** and running the command with **--fix-missing**. Both did not get me any further. I have even tried **apt-get clean**, then **apt-get update** but with the same result. I have also checked the Ubuntu software updater.

When navigating to the mentioned URL [here](http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-rospkg-modules/) it seems like that package has a newer version. The error mentions 1.2.6-1 while the site mentions 1.2.8-1... This was similar for the colcon package errors that I got earlier.

Additional information: uname -r returns kernel: 5.4.0-37-generic, architecture is amd64.

Is the package broken, or is it me? Can I do something about it? Should I simply wait for the packages and/or version information to be updated?

It feels like I am almost there, but I'm not getting anywhere at the moment. I hope someone can help and/or explain. If there is more information required, please mention it. Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Frank

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355673/how-to-fetch-newer-foxy-desktop-packages?/) by [FrankHx](https://answers.ros.org/users/56052/frankhx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I had previously installed foxy desktop through the installation instructions, over two weeks ago.

Please *always* include a link to any tutorials or instructions you refer to in your question text, as otherwise we cannot know *which* instructions you've followed.

As there are quite a few different ones, this is important information.

> Is the package broken, or is it me? Can I do something about it? Should I simply wait for the packages and/or version information to be updated?

Have you ran a `sudo apt update`?

Package indices change as new packages are released.

You need to tell `apt` to update its internal copy of those indices, as otherwise it will try to fetch packages (ie: URLs) which don't exist any more.

You do that with a `sudo apt update`. *Then* try running your `apt install` command again.

Alternatively, the Ubuntu Software (or whatever it is called on Focal) and/or the Ubuntu software updates tool should alert you about the availability of updates.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FrankHx](https://answers.ros.org/users/56052/frankhx/) on 2020-06-24**:
Thanks for your reply. I had already tried what you mentioned, and have edited my question accordingly.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-24**:\

> I had already tried what you mentioned

Then it would have been good if you'd have included that in your OP.

In any case: does `apt update` return any errors?

Can you check to make sure you (still) have the correct key installed? #q325039 provides some info on how to check that.

**Comment by [FrankHx](https://answers.ros.org/users/56052/frankhx/) on 2020-06-24**:
I did not get errors with `sudo apt update`, although without sudo it complains about locking.. AFAIK apt commands should always be done with sudo, right?
Anyway, I have performed the instructions of the question you referred to (updating the key), but the installation still fails on fetching python3-rospkg-modules...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-24**:
Looking at [packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages](http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages) and searching for `python3-rospkg-modules` does link me to `pool/main/p/python3-rospkg-modules/python3-rospkg-modules_1.2.8-1_all.deb`, so that would seem to be correct.

Something is not right on your machine.

Can you `wget http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-rospkg-modules/python3-rospkg-modules_1.2.8-1_all.deb`?

Could you try a `sudo apt clean && sudo apt update`? Perhaps your local caches are corrupt somehow.

**Comment by [FrankHx](https://answers.ros.org/users/56052/frankhx/) on 2020-06-24**:
The `wget` command seems to work fine, I did not see errors. Somehow, it seems that after that `wget` and `sudo apt clean && sudo apt update` it went beyond fetching packages, and I have been able to install Foxy again successfully. Strangely I had already tried the `clean` and `update` before...
Anyway, thanks! I have been able to install Foxy and installed and used colcon :)